# Problem with dataflow job accessing external URLs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow

i have a dataflow job which executes the following code

```
>>> import urllib.request
>>> headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) '
... }
>>> element = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/full-index/2019/QTR1/master.idx'
>>> req = urllib.request.Request(element, headers=headers)
>>> data = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
>>> data =  [line for line in data]
>>> data[0:2]
[b'Description:           Master Index of EDGAR Dissemination Feed\n', b'Last Data Received:    March 31, 2019\n']
```

Now, exactly the same code is embedded in a dataflow job. The job is being ran using a flex template using gcloud, in the following way

```
gcloud dataflow flex-template run "edgarflow23" \
--template-file-gcs-location "$TEMPLATE_PATH" \
--parameters year=2020 \
--parameters quarter=QTR1 \
--parameters setup_file="/dataflow/template/setup.py" \
--region "$REGION"
```

And the code end up in a HTTP 403 Forbidden error
Now when i run exactly the same code via cloud shell, i am getting exactly the same error

- When i run on my local machine, it works fine
- When i kick off the same dataflow job via classic template, it is working fine.

I am puzzled to see where the problem is?
Could anyone help?
regards
marco

Comment: In order to better help you, please share the following details:
- The complete error trace
- Where in the process are you getting the error?
- In Cloud Shell, what's the command you are using in order to run the job?
- Are the project and credentials the same for all environments? (i.e. local, cloud shell and flex templates)

Comment: Hello thannks for getting back to me. Well the stack trace just says ERROR 403 forbidden, and all i am doing is to  open an URL using python's request. I have treid to launch the job either using  gcloud dataflow flex-template run  or by using gcloud beta builds submit   , but  no luck w hatsoever. The external URL does not get loaded. Noticeable, when i run exactly the same code using a classic template, the code works just fine. So i am not quite sure where the problem is

Answer (score 0):

this has been resolved. Nothing to do with CloudBuild, Flex or anything else
It was due to incorrect headers passed when opening an URL

regards